# Load data list in same registration page JSP and Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a registration form and table in the same page but my table only load data when i submit a new registration. How can i load the table when i open the page? Im using JSP and Servlet. I tried to search before asking here but i didnt find what i need.

**index.jsp**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">CÓDIGO</th>
                <th scope="col">DATA</th>
                <th scope="col">QUANTIDADE</th>
                <th scope="col">VALOR</th>
                <th scope="col">VOLUME</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${investimentos}" var="inv">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${inv.codigo}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${inv.data}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${inv.quantidade}"></c:out></td>
                    <td>R$<c:out value="${inv.valor}"></c:out></td>
                    <td>R$<c:out value="${inv.valor * inv.quantidade}"></c:out></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet("/registrarAcao")
public class Acao extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AcaoDAO acaoDAO = new AcaoDAO();

    public Acao() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            req.setAttribute("investimentos", acaoDAO.listar());
            view.forward(req, res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String codigo = req.getParameter("codigo");
        String dataString = req.getParameter("data");

        String quantidade = req.getParameter("quantidade");
        String valor = req.getParameter("valor");

        AcaoBean acao = new AcaoBean();
        acao.setCodigo(codigo);
        acao.setData(dataString);
        acao.setQuantidade(Double.parseDouble(quantidade));
        acao.setValor(Double.parseDouble(valor));
        acaoDAO.salvar(acao);

        try {
            RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            req.setAttribute("investimentos", acaoDAO.listar());
            view.forward(req, res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant view the table if you start with /index.jsp

Comment: Provide the steps that you've already tried.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant view the table if you start with `/index.jsp`. You need to start with `/registrarAcao` and you will get to `doGet` method and you table will be loaded

Change welcome page

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.page</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Worked when i change to `<welcome-file>registrarAcao</welcome-file>` thank you